# can I backup pi3 to a image file remotely to macbook?

Tags: pi-3, backup

My pi3 is placed 300+ kilometers away and I can't reach it frequently(probably 2 times a year).

I would like to backup the disk image remotely once a month, almost all tutorials I found are for which could hold it in hand.

I have a macbook and windows desktop(putty/winscp ready, but I need diskimage backup), is there a way for me to do that remotely?

I have working openvpn between pi and my local PCs.

Comment: I have working openvpn between pi and my local PCs.

Comment: Do you really need a complete image? Or is it also possible to make classical backups of all files?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a disk backup on a running system by reading `/dev/sda`, or whatever the name of your disk is.

However, a disk backup will not necessarily be consistent, and it will occupy space for blocks that are not allocated.

So a better approach specifically for a PI would be to make a disk backup of the partition table and the first partition, and then use `tar` or `rsync` to make a copy of the main file system.